# Como inhabilitar un menu dropdown de boostrap?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap, jsp

Tengo el siguiente método en el controller de inicio que me direcciona a la pantalla del menu

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/menu", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String mostrarMenu(){
  return "/menu";
}
```

este es el jsp del menu

```html
<li>
 <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vista/MenuInicial"> MENU INICIAL
</li>

<li class="active">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"> OPCIONES
  <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
 
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li id="1"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vista/Menu1">MENU 1</a></li>
  <li id="2"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vista/Menu1">MENU 2</a></li>
  <li id="3"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vista/Menu1">MENU 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al cargar la pagina, el Menu Inicial  este activo y me muestre su formulario, osea que resalte que estoy colocado en esa parte y que el menu de OPCIONES este inhabilitado, o sea que si alguien quiere dar clic
en alguna de las opciones desplegables no pueda acceder a ellas

En el Menu Inicial hay un formulario y quiero que al ser llenado, al elegir una opción de un select este dispare un evento y ya te permita seleccionar alguna opción del menu desplegable de OPCIONES

Como puedo hacer eso?

tengo este otro metodo en otro controlador que dispara el formulario del menu "MENU INICIAL"

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/menuInicial", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String mostrarMenuInicial(){
  return "/menuInicial";
}
```

y su jsp con los selects, que al llenar el ultimo este lance un evento para habilitar el menu OPCIONES desplegable

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo1">Combo 1</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="combo1">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-sm-2" for="Combo2">Combo 2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="combo2">
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

 </div>
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 1):

no se si esto te podria servir, pero podrias utilizar `class='disabled'` de bootstrap para desabilitar las opciones
si no entendi mal, tenes que controlar si los select estan llenos para reabilitar el menu de opciones ahi prodrias utilizar un if fijandote el lenght ejemplo :
**codigo editado**

```
//HTML
 <option disabled> opción <option>
//JQUERY
if ($('#mySelectList > option').length == 2) {
    $('#menuOpciones').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#menuOpciones').prop("disabled", false); //para reabilitar
}
```

*este nuevo pedazo te ayuda a cambiar un atributo, en este caso tenemos el disabled que esta activo osea en true, cuando se termina de rellenar la lista le decimos que active las opciónes metiendo el disabled en false*

en caso [aca](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-active&stacked=h) podes encontrar un ejemplo de la class en accion

espero que te sirva

Comment: ya le agregue el class y si sale el icono como de inhabilitado, pero aún así,  si le doy clic en cualquier opción me redirección a la página

Comment: para inhabilitar una opción le tendrias que agregar el attributo disabled --> `<option disabled> opción </option>` que tambien le podes jugar con jquery, ahora te agrego un ejemplo en la respuesta editandola